# React copy to clipboard using useRef hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, clipboard

I'm trying to handle copy to clipboard in `React` with `useRef` hook. How can I achieve it without any additional libraries? Here is my code but it throws an error `myRef.current.select is not a function`.

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";

const Element = () => {
  const myRef = useRef();

  const copyToClipboard = () => {
    myRef.current.select();
    document.execCommand("copy");
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <span onClick={copyToClipboard} ref={myRef}>
        Text to be copied
      </span>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Element;
```

Comment: const myRef = useRef(null);

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't make it work. I have noticed that if I change <span> to <textarea> then it works just fine. Is there a way to copy text from span and not from textarea?

Comment: it copies inside inputs only

Comment: @BaruchMashasha I didn't read your comment before answer but infact you are right. It works only with input (as I saw). Do you know why?

Comment: @DmitryDev yes, it doesn't work with span, but there are way how to achieve it, I posted my answer with another solution.

Answer (score 5):

Run the following snippet(s).

1. Have a separate `CopyToClipElement` component (with React Hooks) which handles the copy for given text prop. Use this component in your render.

```js
const CopyToClipElement = ({ text }) => {
  const myRef = React.useRef(null);
  const [data, setData] = React.useState(text);
  React.useEffect(() => setData(text), [text]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (myRef.current && data) {
      myRef.current.select();
      document.execCommand("copy");
      setData(null);
    }
  }, [data, myRef.current]);

  return <div>{data && <textarea ref={myRef}>{data}</textarea>}</div>;
};

const Element = () => {
  const [copyText, setCopyText] = React.useState("");
  const data = ["Text to be copied", "Copy foo"];

  return (
    <div>
      {data.map((text) => (
        <span
          style={{ margin: "10px", cursor: "pointer", color: 'blue' }}
          onClick={() => setCopyText(text)}
        >
          {text}
        </span>
      ))}
      <CopyToClipElement text={copyText} />
    </div>
  );
};

const domContainer = document.querySelector('#app');
ReactDOM.render(<Element/>, domContainer);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"> </div>
```

2. Alternatively, Just add the utility method `copyToClipboard` in plain JS.

```js
const copyToClipboard = (text: string) => {
  const ta = document.createElement("textarea");
  ta.innerText = text;
  document.body.appendChild(ta);
  ta.select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  ta.remove();
};

const Element = () => {
  const data = ["Text to be copied", "Copy Bar"];

  return (
    <div>
      {data.map((text) => (
        <span
          style={{ margin: "10px", cursor: "pointer", color: 'red' }}
          onClick={() => copyToClipboard(text)}
        >
          {text}
        </span>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

const domContainer = document.querySelector('#app');
ReactDOM.render(<Element />, domContainer);
```

```html
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

    <div id="app"> </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [this solution](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/04/cut-and-copy-commands), I just adapted it to your use case.

```
  const copyToClipboard = () => {
    const range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNode(myRef.current);
    window.getSelection().addRange(range);

    try {
      // Now that we've selected the anchor text, execute the copy command
      const successful = document.execCommand('copy');
      const msg = successful ? 'successful' : 'unsuccessful';
      console.log('Copy email command was ' + msg);
    } catch(err) {
      console.log('Oops, unable to copy');
    }

    // Remove the selections - NOTE: Should use
    // removeRange(range) when it is supported
    window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
  };
```

Comment: I believe it doesn't work because the text I try to copy is inside the <span> element and not inside an <input> element. So the only solution would be to change <span> to <input >, at least I didn't find any other solution...

Comment: @DmitryDev did you try my solution? Just tested in `JSFiddle` and it works.

Comment: [you can try it here](https://jsfiddle.net/n_litvin/ngx4a8ok/24/)

Comment: Yeap, it works, for some reason it didn't work the first time. That's definitely another way to do it. I believe I come up with a more simple solution with a bit of less code. Please see my response to Giovanni's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Ciao, I found a solution but I had to use `input` instead of `span`. And I haven't used `useRef` hook but just a variable (`let myInput = null;`) and then on input ref I wrote `ref={(ref) => myInput = ref}`. In this way, your `copyToClipboard` works.

The code:

```
function App() {
  let myInput = null;
  const copyToClipboard = () => {
    myInput.select();
    document.execCommand("copy");
    alert("Copied the text: " + myInput.value);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input readOnly value="Text to copy" onClick={copyToClipboard} ref={(ref) => myInput = ref} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-counter-demo-forked-9lsol?file=/src/index.js) the codesandbox example.

Comment: You actually gave me a really nice idea. I haven't realised I can use readOnly property on input. So I changed <span> to <input> and added readOnly. Now you can style it with css to look like a span element or whatever you want and you don't actually need to change the structure of the code. So I guess it is also another way to do it. Grazie!

Comment: Yes of course you can do that. Happy to help you. Prego :)